# monoidal (∞,1)-categories from weakly monoidal model categories

Tags: model-categories, monoidal-categories, infinity-categories

In *Higher Algebra* section 4.1.7, Jacob Lurie proves that the underlying $(\infty,1)$-category of a monoidal model category is a monoidal $(\infty,1)$-category.

Dominic Verity and Yuki Maehara have (independently) defined the lax Gray tensor product for model categories $S$ and $T$ for two different models of $(\infty,2)$-categories and proved that their tensor product is "weakly monoidal" in various senses:

- Maehara provides functors $\otimes_n \colon T^{\times n} \to T$ for each $n \geq 2$ that define the left adjoint parts of $n$-variable Quillen adjunctions. But these functors are associative in a weak sense, eg with a zig zag of natural weak equivalences

$$ X \otimes_2 (Y \otimes_2 Z) \to \otimes_3(X,Y,Z) \leftarrow (X \otimes_2 Y) \otimes_2 Z.$$

- Verity constructs two binary tensor products $\otimes, \otimes' \colon S \times S \to S$ that are naturally weakly equivalent, one of which is a closed left Quillen bifunctor and the other of which is associative up to isomorphism.

Morally, this weakness should not matter for the underlying $(\infty,1)$-category, but has anyone verified that a monoidal structure on the underlying $(\infty,1)$-category can be produced under these weaker hypotheses?

Alternatively, would someone like to take this on? I'd be happy to help publicize a result along these lines whenever it appears.

(FYI: Andrea Gagna, Yonatan Harpaz, Edoardo Lanari have a third version of the lax Gray tensor product that defines a monoidal model category in the usual sense. But I'm still interested in the question of about weak monoidal model categories, which is why I've set this aside.)

Comment: Ignoring the model structure, I would like to call the situation of the first bullet a "lax monoidal category" (or maybe "oplax"?). I've only seen lax monoidal categories (or rather their dual) in one source, namely [Higher Algebra Definition 6.2.4.3](http://people.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/HA.pdf#page=1108) where they're called "corepresentable ($\infty$-)operads" (of course, it's jazzed up to be $\infty$ everything). I think another example of a (op)lax monoidal category (interacting nicely with a model structure) would be Boardman's handicrafted smash products of spectra.

Comment: It's conceivable that Lurie's framework might even be helpful here -- if you're interested mostly in the $\infty$-category presented by your model category, then maybe some of Lurie's general results on localization for $\infty$-operads could be used to say things like "there is a monoidal structure on the presented $\infty$-category".

Comment: Localization is a product-preserving functor from relative categories to $\infty$-categories. That means it's compatible with the enrichment of each category in itself, which should give you enough structure to say a functor of 2-categories to the 2-category of relative categories gives after localization one to the $(\infty,2)$-category of $\infty$-categories, which would give another approach to the first part. Unfortunately this kind of naturality for enrichments from module structures hasn't been worked out yet, however, though I believe Hadrian Heine is working on this.

Comment: Hiya Emily, nice to see you here.  I think that this question was explored in the paper by Heuts, Hinich, and Moerdijk that fixes all of the mistakes from Moerdijk-Weiss.  I'm not sure if they verified transport of structure to the associated ∞-category, but it's another data point: https://arxiv.org/abs/1305.3658

Comment: In the second situation, isn't the full subcategory of pre-complicial sets a genuine monoidal model category?

Comment: @TimCampion Yuki's structure is indeed an example of a lax monoidal category (which is the standard name in the literature). Lurie's "corepresentable operads" correspond to (symmetric) colax monoidal categories. Of course, the opposite of a lax monoidal category is a colax monoidal category, so I agree that this a promising approach.

Comment: @AlexanderCampbell Great, that's good to know! Regarding pre-complicial sets, Verity indeed showed that the Gray tensor product is monoidal biclosed on them, and Yuki, Chris Kaupulkin and I observed in Theorem 1.33 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.07603.pdf#page=10) that the usual model structures are monoidal with respect to it. Relatedly, in that same preprint, we construct a monoidal biclosed lax Gray tensor product on a category of marked cubical sets (without having to futz around with the category _a la_ precomplicial sets) and show it's a monoidal model category.

Comment: @TimCampion Excellent!

Comment: There was further discussion in chat. To sum up: the suggestion from my second comment was [misguided](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55366151#55366151) because Lurie really only deals in _reflective_ localizations, and so can't say much about the localization from a model category to its associated $\infty$-category. But Rune [points out](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55373635#55373635) that Hinich has results on how DK localization interacts with cocartesian fibrations which could do the trick if generalized to the locally cocartesian case.